# Getting error when using the .fit (linear Regression)

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, linear-regression, prediction

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/seemarahul/Downloads/adult-1.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:,0:15].values

Y = dataset['income']

y_train: object
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test= train_test_split(X,Y,shuffle=True,test_size=0.3)

lin = LinearRegression()

lin.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = lin.predict(X_test)


coef  = lin.coef_
components = pd.DataFrame(zip(X.columns,coef), columns=['component','value'])
components = components.append({'components':'intercept','value':lin.intercept_}, ignore_index=True )
```

This is My code its getting some error & is is getting redirected to **base.py**

this line is getting error

`lin.fit(X_train,y_train)`

I have tried multiple way of adding data to the X and Y variables
none is working

[The image if of the traceback Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqYzI.png)

Comment: What is the error?  Please add the traceback.

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual text, not an image of the text.

Comment: @James Traceback is been added

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error.  It tells you that you have a value `'Private'` exists in either your `X` or `Y` variable.  It looks like it is in `X` based on the fifth line of the traceback.

`'Private'` is a string and cannot be cast to a float, so it raises the error.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to keep it string itself

Comment: You cannot if you want to use linear regression.

Comment: So I'll need to convert the datafile into foat and that should work right?